# fileExists(atPath: <Path of Symbolic link> ) returns false is symlink target doesn't exist? A bug?

Tags: swift, foundation

Is anybody fell on that?

I did many tries. So if the targeted file exists the symbolic link if reported as found by the function if not the function returns false.

I dug the library to find a way to work around that.

Maybe using attributesOfItem(atPath:) as tester?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901378/how-can-i-tell-if-a-symbolic-link-exists-at-a-certain-path

Comment: Thanks Cristik. I had looked for but didn't find it.